# Problem to iterate through objects in database with spring/thymeleaf

Tags: java, mysql, spring, thymeleaf

Recently I started to create my clone project for Splitwise. The problem is that I can't iterate through my Users from the database, even tho they exist and are written in the console.

https://github.com/DamianKwc/SplitwiseProject.git

The web is opening correctly as well as the template but there are no objects. This is my first time here, sorry for any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
<tr th:each="userList : ${theUsers}">
    <td th:text="${user.id_user}"></td>
    <td th:text="${user.user_name}"></td>
    <td th:text="${user.username}"></td>
</tr>
```

with

```
<tr th:each="theUsers : ${userList}">
    <td th:text="${theUsers.id_user}"></td>
    <td th:text="${theUsers.user_name}"></td>
    <td th:text="${theUsers.login}"></td>
</tr>
```

The userList needs to match the value that you assigned in your controller with this line

```
theModel.addAttribute("userList", theUsers);
```

`theUsers` is the variable name that you will use to represent each object while you iterate through the list.

And all fields need to match the fields of your entity, NOT your database. Your database User field is called `"username"`, but in your entity class it is named `login` and what you need to do is to iterate through fields of your entity, not your database fields.

https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-iteration

Comment: Thank you very much, I cant believe it was that simple !

Comment: Yeah, once you do it right it's a piece of cake.